# How do i plot a Matlab imagesc-like plot purely in Latex

Tags: pgfplots, pdftex, plot

```
for i = 1:length(RVs) 
    for j=1:length(MVs)
      load(data)% load some data.
      sumRRE(j) = mean((RRE< 1e-10));
    end  
    RREs(:,i) = sumRRE;
    clear summRRE;  
end
 % in the end RREs is a matrix of 9-by-10
RV = [10:10:100]; % x-axis
MV = 0.1:0.1:0.9; % y- axis
 
imagesc(RV,MV,RREs);
colorbar()
```

The following code works in Matlab. but im wondering if i can do same in latex as latex plots are much nicer. My RREs matrix is  9-by-10 in dimension. Below is my attempt, but it doesnt work. Here is a [link](https://www.sendspace.com/file/ena7lk) to the data file to try. Thanks in advance.

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Missing Value Prop},
    ylabel={Rendezvous Prop},
    xtick={10, 20, ..., 100},
    ytick={0.1, 0.2, ..., 0.9},
    y dir=reverse,
    colormap={mycolormap}{color=(white) color=(blue)},
    colorbar,
    point meta min=0,
    point meta max=1,
]
\addplot[matrix plot*, mesh/rows=9] table [x index=0, y index=1, meta index=2] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you should add the contents of the file you link directly to this question. Not everybody likes to follow links to some site on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the x and y values in the table, so your table format should be `x y C` instead of a C matrix (here your RREs matrix). I added some lines to your Matlab Code to transform the data to the correct format for latex.

(I couldn't run your Matlab Code since there are undefined variables but loading your linked data instead let me skip the loop completely.)

```matlab
load("data2.dat")
RREs = data2;

% in the end RREs is a matrix of 9-by-10
RV = 10:10:100; % x-axis
MV = 0.1:0.1:0.9; % y- axis

figure(1)
colormap(flipud(gray))
imagesc(RV,MV,RREs);
colorbar()

% Transform the data into table format for Latex
[X,Y] = meshgrid(RV,MV);
data_table = [reshape(X',[],1), reshape(Y',[],1), reshape(RREs',[],1)];
writematrix(data_table,"data_trafo.dat","Delimiter",'\t')
```

With that, your Code almost works fine. I only added the option `point meta=explicit` so that latex expects and uses the given numerical point data.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Missing Value Prop},
    ylabel={Rendezvous Prop},
    xtick={10, 20, ..., 100},
    ytick={0.1, 0.2, ..., 0.9},
    y dir=reverse,
    colormap={mycolormap}{color=(white) color=(blue)},
    colorbar,
    point meta min=0,
    point meta max=1,
]
\addplot[matrix plot*, mesh/rows=9, mesh/cols=10,point meta=explicit] table [x index=0, y index=1, meta index=2] {data_trafo.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This should result in something like this. I hope this is what you are looking for.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, a lot, this is perfect.